# Gitlab CI/CD yml file to build, package and deploy .net standard class library as nuget to nexus repository

Tags: nuget, gitlab, nexus, gitlab-ci, .net-standard

I have a `.net Standard (.Net Standard 2.0)` class library which I want to deploy to `nexus` as `nuget package`. The private nexus repository is ready and I'm using `Gitlab` for code management.

In Gitlab I added the gitlab-ci.yml file which will trigger the build and the deployment but still without enough steps:

```
stages:
  - build
  - package
  - deploy

build_image:
  stage: build  
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Restoring NuGet Packages…"
    - RUN dotnet restore
    - echo "Building solution…"
    - RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o

package_dev:
  stage: package
  script:
    - 

deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: development
  only:
    - master
  script:
    -
```

My question is how to configure this file to trigger a build then perform `packaging and deploy/push to nexus repo`?

I don't know if I described it well as i'm totally new to this topic. I found some examples using `MAVEN` image but we are not using it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works fine for me. Here is the script in case anybody faces the same issue/requirement:

In `ci.yml` on `deploy` stage:

```
stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
    - nuget restore mysolution.sln

deploy_mysolution:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: crunchtime/dotnetcore-nuget-msbuild-docker
  script:
    - dotnet msbuild mysolution.sln /t:Clean,ReBuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"
    - dotnet pack "mysolution/myproject.csproj" /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"
    - PKGPATH=$(find myproject/bin/Release/*.nupkg)
    - dotnet nuget push $PKGPATH -k $NUGET_PUSH_KEY -s https://nexus.xyz.com/repository/nuget/
  only:
    - master
```

where `$NUGET_PUSH_KEY` is the api key which is saved as an env variable which is applied to environments via the runner.

Comment: How can I reference custom package in gitlab-ci.yml file. I have ldap nuget package in root directory. I tried dotnet build --source /package-directory but i am getting ```error NU1101: Unable to find package LDAPLoginAuthentication. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org``` Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a nuget package out of your project and upload it to Nexus Repo. You can do it one step.

```
build-and-upload:
  image: <dot-net image>
  stage: build-and-upload
  environment:
    name: dev/test/prod
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - aws commands if you need to assume a deploy role.
  script:
    - ./scripts/nuget_publish.sh




And this is how your nuget_publish.sh will look like

dotnet build
dotnet pack
NEXUS_SOURCE=<Nexus_Source_Repo_Url>
NEXUS_API_KEY=<Nexus_Source_Repo_Api_Key>
dotnet nuget push <ProjectName>/bin/Debug/*.nupkg --source $NEXUS_SOURCE --api-key $NEXUS_API_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i actually solved this issue before your post already. I will post my answer in sometime so you can take a look on it.

Comment: Ahaan.. Perfect!!